# Android SQLite - how to combine database expression with union or join statement

Tags: android, sqlite, join, union

I have a table with money items stored in it, by date.
Some money items are typed as loan and others as borrow.

With my request I would like to get firstly all the loan money, by month (with the strftime function), and union them (or join don't know) with all the borrow money by month.

So if I have, for a dedicated month, only a loan item or only a borrow item, I still want to catch it.

I will then use the results to display a two bar chart graphics.

Here is my sql statement :

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT date_o, loan, borrow FROM " +
                        "(SELECT strftime('%m', date) AS date_o, SUM(amount) AS loan, '0' AS borrow FROM " +
                        "(SELECT date, amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date > date('now', '-6 months') AND TYPE = " + ActivityClass.DATABASE_LOAN_TYPE + " ORDER BY date DESC) " +
                        "GROUP BY strftime('%m', date) " +
                        "UNION ALL " +
                        "SELECT strftime('%m', date) AS date_o, '0' AS loan, SUM(amount) AS borrow FROM " +
                        "(SELECT date, amount FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE date > date('now', '-6 months') AND TYPE = " + ActivityClass.DATABASE_BORROW_TYPE + " ORDER BY date DESC) " +
                        "GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)) GROUP BY date_o", null);
```

It seems that the statement after the UNION erase all the loan items with 0.
I checked on the net the LEFT OUTER JOIN, but still trying to understand how this could answer to my needs.

Finally, what I would like to have is smthg like that :

This is my table:

```
Date          Amnt  Type
01/12/2016    15    Borrow
05/12/2016    10    Loan
01/11/2016    20    Loan
19/11/2016    10    Loan
01/10/2016    15    Borrow
```

This is what I want (after having regroup with strftime to have sum by month:

```
Month         SUM(loan)   SUM(borrow)
10            0           15
11            30          0
12            10          15
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output.

Comment: `UNION` and `JOIN` are 'operators', the code either side of them are 'table expressions'.